# GridView with textfields Not Working properly when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a very simple grid view in which each item consists of two textfields. When scrolling, the grid view items assumes random values on items which were beneath the scroll page. I am new to this so please help!
My adapter is as follows

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;
private final String[] web1;

public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,String[] web1 ) {
    mContext = c;
    this.web1 = web1;
    this.web = web;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ItemType);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ItemOutput);
        textView1.setText(web[position]);
        textView2.setText(web1[position]);

    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

}

And my mainactivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;
ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Google",
        "Github",
        "Instagram",
        "Facebook",
        "Vine",
        "Pinterest",
        "Quora",
        "Twitter",
        "Vimeo",
        "WordPress",
        "Youtube",
        "Stumbleupon",
        "SoundCloud",
        "Reddit",
        "Blogger"));

ArrayList<String> abc1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
        "13",
        "14",
        "15"));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final String[] web = abc.toArray(new String[abc.size()]);
    final String[] web1 = abc1.toArray(new String[abc1.size()]);

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web1, web);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

```
int actualPosition;    

    if(convertView != null) {
        actualPosition = ((GridView)parent).getPositionForView(convertView);
    }
```

It would return the actual position no matter what also avoiding the null error which I got few times.

It happens because when scrolling, GridView is updated but not the position variable in getView().

Comment: Didn't understand where to actually place this snippet of code. Please help ASAP.

Comment: I dont know why you used convertView == null, so i gave you an overview, you need to get the position from convertView variable itself, as, when old child of GridView comes at bottom, position variable doesn't get the new value, but you can get it with convertView

Comment: In else part, do,
`int actualPosition = ((GridView)parent).getPositionForView(convertView);`
Then,
`TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemType);
textView1.setText(web[actualPosition]);`